# ROS system randomly crashes and gdb says corrupt stack in callback queue

Tags: ros, gdb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My ROS system randomly crashes and I decided to run gdb at all times to catch it next time it happens.

I caught it and this is the output from gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x6deff420 (LWP 25232)]
0x0003d210 in boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release() ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0003d210 in boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release() ()
#1  0x76409570 in ros::SubscriptionQueue::call() () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
#2  0x763baa84 in ros::CallbackQueue::callOneCB(ros::CallbackQueue::TLS*) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
#3  0x6defec5c in ?? ()
#4  0x6defec5c in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Obviously that is not much help! Does anyone have an idea how I can go about debugging this? Point me in the right direction? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231123/ros-system-randomly-crashes-and-gdb-says-corrupt-stack-in-callback-queue/) by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 363 on 2016-04-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mrrius](https://answers.ros.org/users/48787/mrrius/) on 2019-11-20**:
I face the same error here. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like stack corruption. I'd start by running your node in valgrind, and if that doesn't find anything I'd start looking for more specific tools for debugging stack overruns.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) on 2016-04-05**:
Thanks. I had heard of valgrind but I've never used it before. I'll give it a look.